# How to ensamble different ranking models?

Tags: classification, ranking, auc, roc

I have trained two different models, which give a score to each data point. The score of the models it is not necessarily comparable.
The score is used to give a ranking, and the performance is measured with AUC and ROC curve.

How can I ensamble the different models to obtain a better AUC and ROC curve?

Comment: Hello Diego, we'd like to have more more information to provide a relevant answer. What exactly is your network achieving and what are your datasets ? it is usually hard to merge datasets, but should be possible if they have similar features. I'm not sure if I understood the question tho, was it about merging datasets or trained models ?

Comment: My dataset has around 10 features, and it is a binary classification problem. However, it is enough to rank the samples such that the first samples are more likely to belong to one of the classes. A normal ensamble doesn't work as the models don't directly predict the class probability, they just give a score.

Comment: Well then the first step would be to use Sigmoid function on model output to get the probability of belonging to one class or another (Sigmoid shrinks the output to [0, 1] : > 0,5 belongs to class 1; < 0,5 belongs to class 0). Then all your networks will have similar outputs and you could try combining them to get a more accurate result

Comment: For clarification, I am using the same dataset for the two models. However, the labels used to train the models are not exactly the same, as they are infered in two different ways

Comment: OK. I finally get your point. Then it's up to you to find how to combine outputs from your networks so you get better results, this completly depends on how you create your labels. Or one way would be to use a last network that works using the outputs of your first networks as inputs

Comment: Ok, I see. And for a last model that makes the ensamble, is there any GAM that ensures montonus (or increasing) partial dependence plots?

Comment: I don't really know about that... I never had to combine networks myself. Can't help you much there

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway. I think using a final network will be the best approach

Comment: I'm probably stating the obvious but the basic way is to average the two ranks.